# Deriving the Interference Intensity of Michelson interferometer

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry, intensity

I am trying to equate the equation i found wikipedia:

> [image: Blockquote]

To the one given in my course notes which is:

> [image: Blockquote]

Assuming a 50/50 beam split i have 1/2 where i should not have one:

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in you trig equation, it should be:

$$[cos(2x)+1]=2cos^{2}(x) $$

Thus you would have:

$$I=I_{s}+I_{s} cos(\frac{2πΔz}{λ})= I_{s}[1+cos⁡(\frac{2πΔz}{λ})]=2I_{s}cos^2⁡(\frac{πΔz}{λ})$$